# Javascript why can one specify callback without parameters?

Tags: javascript, callback, handler

I originally come from the Java Programming language, and I was just wondering why it is possible in javascript to pass a callback function as a variable or plain object (without parameters) to another function, and then use this callback function inside of another function but this time with parameters to pass.

And how exactly is this callback returning my user object, as I  did not specify a return function inside `callback(user)`, or specify any function body at all for my callback. Is this done inside the `setTimeout(()...)` function as the `timeoutHandler` implementation is implicitly returning something?

```
var getUser = (id,callback) => {
    var user = {
        id: id,
        name: 'Vikram'
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(user);
    },3000);    
};


getUser(31, (userObject) => {
    console.log(userObject);
});
```

Comment: _"as I did not specify a return function inside callback(user), or specify any function body at all for my callback"_ - You have... `(userObject) => {console.log(userObject);});` (which is the same as `function(userObject) { return console.log(userObject); }`)

Comment: It's not the same. It's not returning console.log(userObject). Rather it's returning undefined.

Comment: @Diljohn5741 in fact `console.log` always returns `undefined` so as long as it's on last line of your function it doesn't matter if you return it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions here:

- **why it is possible in javascript to pass a callback function as a variable or plain object (without parameters) to another function.**

Because functions are first-class objects, we can pass a function as an argument in another function and later execute that passed-in function or even return it to be executed later.

Read more here: https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Below shows functions are just objects as well:

```
function hello() {
  return 'hello';
}

hello.other = 'world';

console.log(hello() + ', ' + hello.other);
```

- **how exactly is this callback returning my user object, as I did not specify a return function inside `callback(user)`, or specify any function body at all for my callback.**

`setTimeout(()...)` function is not implicitly returning anything, it just registers a function, that would execute later. When the function registered by the setTimeout triggers, it invokes the `callback(user)` and that resolves `getUser` registered function which logs to the console. Remember callbacks are asynchronous.

Functions have implicit returns if not specified, which returns `undefined`, meaning you did not explicitly return.

Below shows an example:

```
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello, World');
}

console.log(hello()); // undefined.

function hi() {
  return 'Hi, World';
}

console.log(hi()); // Hi, World.
```

Comment: ok thanks, I think the thing I didnt understand was, that I defined my callback function inside getUser(id, (parameter)=>{})... as an anonymous function, with one parameter, that was unknown to me as a Java developer ;) so it was rather a javascript function definition case of question I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The function i.e callback is passed as reference here. So you can pass it as much you want, when you call it then you can pass on the arguments and it will refer to original function.

And also it's not returning the user object, it's just consoling out the user object. As you have not used any return it will return undefined. Try consoling the callback fn return out.

```
var getUser = (id,callback) => {
var user = {
    id: id,
    name: 'Vikram'
};

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(callback(user), 'return value of callback');
},3000);
```

};

Comment: ok the callback is passed as reference here, but how can I pass a parameter to callback(parameter), if I have not defined my callback with any parameters, and then just simply use this function somewhere below: function(userObject) {console.log(userObject)}, which gets "mapped" essentially to my callback function reference... or if I understand right here, I defined my callback(parameter) function exactly in the last getUser() function as an anonymous function if I am right? and its called on top as "callback" function object reference? (so it essentially still has the parameter def below)

Comment: Yes you are right, you are passing the function definition while calling getUser. As functions are also treated as objects in JS, they are passed as reference to getUser. So you can pass this "callback" to any function within getUser and it will still hold reference to what you are passing while calling the getUser. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: ok thanks, I just find it really confusing, sometimes I think that this function is being executed in the same place where I have defined it, but thats wrong of course, it just gets passed and executed on the callback site...

Answer (score 0):

1. In javascript function is a object.
   It behaves like function only with `()`
   So you can pass function to another function or variable as value.
2. Some functions in javascript are asynchronous.
   setTimeout is such async function. It means callback function will be run after a time.

What's happening:

```
//assign anonymous function to variable
// until function without () it only a object
var getUser = (id,callback) => {
    //set up params
    var user = {
        id: id,
        name: 'Vikram'
    };

    // setup asynchronous function setTimeout
    setTimeout(() => {
        // run callback with params when time would done
        callback(user);
    },3000);
};

// call function which contains in getUser-variable and pass 2 params: int and callback-function
getUser(31, (userObject) => {
    console.log(userObject);
});
```